# 'expo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, expo

I am getting this error when I try to use expo commands.

> npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! syscall rename npm ERR! path
> C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli npm ERR! dest
> C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.expo-cli-JgrrLjT2 npm
> ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted,
> rename 'C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli' ->
> 'C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.expo-cli-JgrrLjT2' npm
> ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename
> 'C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli' ->
> 'C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.expo-cli-JgrrLjT2'] {
> npm ERR!   errno: -4048, npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM', npm ERR!   syscall:
> 'rename', npm ERR!   path:
> 'C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli', npm
> ERR!   dest:
> 'C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.expo-cli-JgrrLjT2'
> npm ERR! } npm ERR! npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your
> operating system. npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in
> use (by a text editor or antivirus), npm ERR! or that you lack
> permissions to access it. npm ERR! npm ERR! If you believe this might
> be a permissions issue, please double-check the npm ERR! permissions
> of the file and its containing directories, or try running npm ERR!
> the command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2020-12-31T06_02_09_505Z-debug.log

> C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli

I followed the above path and found that expo-cli folder was there but when I try to init or uninstall expo it says 'expo' is not recognized as internal or external command.

Answer (score 0):

if your in right directory perhaps the binary you are trying to execute does'nt exist there  ,maybe the executable is named something else and if you are trying from another directory you should add the executable to system variables [here's the link to do so](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

Comment: I have added system variables also and expo folder also can be found in the following path : C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli                                                But nothing changed

Comment: Maybe you are typing the wrong spells or as i mentioned the exe file might be named differently cuz if the path is right and the program is present then it should work..